# NetSuite - Check if user is properly logged

Tags: netsuite

I have a little question. I am working with NetSuite eCommerce and I need to check something, my site runs a script when user is logged, but sometimes it asks for a login even when still getting NetSuite Attributes. Something like this:

```
var loginEmail = "<%=getCurrentAttribute('customer','email')%>";
if(loginEmail==null || loginEmail=="") {
   $("#cart").hide();
}
else {
   $("#cart").show();
}
```

Do you know a specific NetSuite attribute or tag that I should be calling/using?

Answer (score 0):

User sessions do time out after a period of inactivity, and user sessions are tracked with a cookie.

Try testing with a different browser - ie run NetSuite in FireFox and test the eCommerce functionality in Chrome or Safari, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `nlapiGetLogin()`. From NetSuite Help:

> #### nlapiGetLogin
>
> Returns the NetSuite login credentials of currently logged-in user.
>
> This API is supported in user event, portlet, Suitelet, RESTlet, and SSP scripts. For information about the unit cost associated with this API, see API Governance.
>
> **Returns** `nlobjLogin`
>
> **Since** Version 2012.2
>
> **Example**
>
> This example shows how to get the credentials of the currently logged-in user.

```
//Get credentials of currently logged-in user
var login = nlapiGetLogin();
```

It doesn't say, but my thought is that this would return `null` if no user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<%
var shoppingSession = nlapiGetWebContainer().getShoppingSession();

if (!shoppingSession.isLoggedIn()) 
    $("#cart").hide();
else
    $("#cart").show();
%>
```

Comment: Hey Benj, this is more like a SS or SSP page, i don't think this will work on a Template. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In place of

```
<%=getCurrentAttribute('customer','email')%>
```

try using

```
<%=getCurrentAttribute('customer','entityid')%>
```